# Trying to make a specific activity the main one

Tags: android

[image: Manifest folder]

I am trying to make login screen the main activity however i receive the error 'activity must be exported or contain an intent filter'. I have also selected it to run from that activity in the Run-Edit configurations settings

[image: edit configuration settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please close the activity tag after intent-filter as:

```
<activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Did that work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap `intent-filter` inside `LoginActivity` tag

```
 <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the `<activity>` tag right on declaration, the intent filter must be inside the node

```
<activity ... >
     <intent filter ...
</activity>
```

I added a snippet of code cause you posted a image of code and actually is a reason for dowvoting.